# How could I get metadata from my Python-Django project to implement the SSO?

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I have a Python-Django project and I'm trying to integrate with a C#/.NET existing website SAML authentication, using their idp.

I absolutely need to generate a metadata file to give to whoever manages the IdP (C#/.NET website). I've been around the Internet for days but can't find anything; I tried with all libraries (pysaml2, djangosaml2, python3-saml, django-saml2-auth, etc.) but it didn't work!

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

**Question**:

I absolutely need to generate a metadata file to give to whoever manages the IdP (C#/.NET website). I've been around the Internet for days but can't find anything; I tried with all libraries (pysaml2, djangosaml2, python3-saml, django-saml2-auth, etc.) but it didn't work!

**Answer**:

PySAML2/pysaml2 is SAML library, and djangosaml2 is SAML Service Provider (SP).

(1) [PySAML2/pysaml2](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2) is a pure python implementation of SAML Version 2 Standard. It contains all necessary pieces for building a SAML2 service provider or an identity provider.

You can use PySAML2 library to develop Python SAML Service Provider (SP) for your Python-Django project, with reference to the source code of [djangosaml2](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/), because the development team of PySAML2 library also develops [djangosaml2](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/) project to instruct how to use [PySAML2](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2) library to develop Python SAML SP.

(2)  [djangosaml2](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/) is a Fully Compliant SAML2 Service Provider which was developed by using PySAML2 library.

[The djangosaml2 Getting Started](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/contents/usage.html) instructs us how to get SAML SP metadata of djangosaml2 by accessing http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/

Thus, after you use PySAML2 library to develop Python SAML SP for your Python-Django project, you can access https://your-Python-Django-app.com/saml2/metadata/ to generate/get Python SAML SP metadata of your Python-Django project, then you can give your Python SAML SP metadata to whoever manages the IdP (C#/.NET website).

(3) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provide an instruction on how to build and run a Shibboleth SAML IdP and SAML SP testbed to test your SAML SP application.

SAML SP can be developed by using the different programming language which is used to develop SAML IdP. Thus, you can also use Java-based Shibboleth IdP to test Python SAML SP, if you upload your SAML SP metadata of Python-Django project to shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata and configure shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/conf/metadata-providers.xml and relying-party.xml.

You can use the above Java-based Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP testbed (which has been validated on Ubuntu 22.04) to get a big picture of the authentication between SAML IdP and SAML SP before you use PySAML2 library to develop Python SAML Service Provider (SP) for your Python-Django project.